# O que significa o operador "|=" em Python?

Tags: python, operadores

Estava analisando um código e me deparei com o operador `|=`, gostaria de saber o que isso significa, e qual é a sua aplicação prática.

Exemplo:

```
x |= y
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assim como o operador `+=` incrementa o valor de uma variável, algo como `x +=y` ser equivalente a `x = x + y`, o operador `|=` executa o **ou binário** entre o valor atual e o outro parâmetro, algo como `x |= y` ser equivalente a `x = x | y`.

O ou binário nada mais é que a operação ou executada bit a bit. Por exemplo, vamos tomar dois números inteiros positivos:

```
x = 5
y = 13
```

Podemos verificar a representação binária de cada valor através da função nativa `bin`.

```
print(bin(x), bin(y)) # 0b101 0b1101
```

Que pode ser expandido para 8 bits para `00000101` e `00001101`. O ou binário fará a operação ou bit a bit, retornando 1 quando pelo menos 1 dos operandos for 1 ou 0 quando ambos forem 0.

```
00000101 | 00001101 = 00001101
```

Perceba que o resultado, neste exemplo, será igual ao segundo operando, então fazer `5 | 13` resulta em 13. Assim:

```
x |= y
print(x) # 13
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/cc6X9N).

### Aplicação

Uma das aplicações mais comuns desse operador é de definir *flags* utilizadas na configurações de algum sistema. *Flags* são comumente valores booleanos, que podem receber apenas valores 0 ou 1. Utilizando o tipo boolean, é comum que compiladores e interpretadores aloquem mais de apenas 1 bit para tal tipo, mesmo que este ocupe, de fato, um único bit. Para contornar isso, é possível armazenar todas as *flags* em um outro tipo de variável, utilizando o operador `|`. Considerando que o tipo `char` seja representado por 8 bits, que é o padrão em C, seria possível armazenar 8 *flags* diferentes em um `char`. Com Python, por ser tipagem dinâmica, isso acaba ficando um pouco abstrato, mas a filosofia por trás acaba sendo a mesma.

Vejamos um exemplo com código:

Vamos considerar que nossa aplicação possuem 8 diferentes opções de configuração. Para simplificar, darei nomes genéricos de A a H:

```
CONFIG_A = 1     # bin: 0b00000001
CONFIG_B = 2     # bin: 0b00000010
CONFIG_C = 4     # bin: 0b00000100
CONFIG_D = 8     # bin: 0b00001000
CONFIG_E = 16    # bin: 0b00010000
CONFIG_F = 32    # bin: 0b00100000
CONFIG_G = 64    # bin: 0b01000000
CONFIG_H = 128   # bin: 0b10000000
```

Perceba que com esses determinados valores inteiros, cada configuração representará apenas um bit na representação binária. Isso permitirá que se a nossa configuração possuir o valor `0b00000101`, significará que as configurações `CONFIG_A` e `CONFIG_C` foram definidas. Esta definição pode ser feita através do operador `|`:

```
config = CONFIG_A | CONFIG_C  # bin: 0b00000101
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/KQZ3NO).

No código, para se verificar se determinada configuração foi definida, basta utilizar a operação inversa `&` (e bit a bit). Por exemplo:

```
def foo(config):
    if (config & CONFIG_A): print("Configuração A foi definida")
    if (config & CONFIG_B): print("Configuração B foi definida")
    if (config & CONFIG_C): print("Configuração C foi definida")
    if (config & CONFIG_D): print("Configuração D foi definida")
    if (config & CONFIG_E): print("Configuração E foi definida")
    if (config & CONFIG_F): print("Configuração F foi definida")
    if (config & CONFIG_G): print("Configuração G foi definida")
    if (config & CONFIG_H): print("Configuração H foi definida")
    print(" -- + --")
```

Testando a função:

```
foo(CONFIG_A)
foo(CONFIG_B | CONFIG_D)
foo(CONFIG_H | CONFIG_E | CONFIG_F)
```

A saída será:

```
Configuração A foi definida
 -- + --
Configuração B foi definida
Configuração D foi definida
 -- + --
Configuração E foi definida
Configuração F foi definida
Configuração H foi definida
 -- + --
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/WIxbiX).

Comment: Suspeitei desde o princípio! A explicação da aplicação ficou perfeita (+1)

Answer (score 10):

Para números inteiros, é o operador de atribuição de compostos bit a bit ou OR. Como todos os operadores de atribuição compostos, `a | = b` é a mesma coisa que `a = a | b`. Onde o `|` é o símbolo de `OR` bit a bit.

> |=    Bitwise inclusive OR
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment
>
> |= (bitwise OR assignment) Performs bitwise OR and assigns value to
>   the left operand.
>   http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/

Meu entendimento após pesquisar... O `|=` atribuirá o valor após executar um `OR` entre duas variáveis, mas bit a bit.

Por exemplo:

```
   0101 (decimal 5)
OR 0011 (decimal 3)
 = 0111 (decimal 7)
```

Outro exemplo:

```
a |= 10 //Supondo que a vale 12.

   1100 (decimal 12)
OR 1010 (decimal 10)
 = 1110 (decimal 14)

//Dessa forma a será igual a 14.
```

Da uma olhada nesse link tirei ele como base. 
É a mesma pergunta que a sua com bastante exemplos e caso de uso:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884075/usecase-of-in-python

Comment: Boa resposta (+1), faltou só exemplificar com uma aplicação prática.