# Usuário com mais de um perfil

Tags: sql, mysqli, modelagem, arquitetura-de-software

Na regra de negócio do sistema que estou trabalhando, um usuário pode ter mais de um perfil. Os perfis são: administrador, avaliador e responsável.

Por exemplo: Fulano pode ser administrador e avaliador ao mesmo tempo.

Minha dúvida é como mapear isso? Eu tive algumas ideias mas não sei se é a melhor forma de fazer isso.

Uma ideia:
Criar uma coluna no banco de dados para cada perfil, por exemplo: is_admin, is_responsible e is_appraiser e ir setando 0 ou 1, de acordo com o perfil do usuário.

Uma outra ideia:
Ter uma coluna no banco de dados, para armazenar só um número que será gerado de acordo com o perfil.

```
Exemplo:
Administrador = 0 
Avaliador = 1
Responsável = 2
Administrador + Avaliador = 4
```

São ideias que eu tive, mas não sei a maneira correta de armazenar isso.

Comment: Acredito que a melhor forma é na tabela do usuário ter apenas uma coluna identificado qual o tipo de perfil do mesmo.

Comment: E se depois aparecer mais um tipo de perfil? O ideal é você fazer uma segunda tabela já que a relação entre usuário e perfil `1:N`.

Comment: Existe hierarquia entre os perfis? Isso controlará permissões? Se sim, o cada grupo faz é exclusivo dele? Ou, por exemplo, administrador por fazer tudo, por padrão?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não há uma hierarquia, são independentes mesmo.

Comment: Esses perfis são estáticos ou dinâmicos? Eles poderiam ser uma enumeração ou poderão surgir novos perfis a qualquer momento?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Eles estão estáticos, sempre serão estes três tipos de perfis.

Comment: Para uma aplicação escalável eu escolheria a resposta do Dherik, e para uma aplicação mais performática e de fácil desenvolvimento a do Anderson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se são perfis estáticos - não existe a possibilidade de criar novos perfis com o tempo de aplicação - você pode definí-los através de uma enumeração com valores sendo potências de 2.

```
enum Perfis {
    Administrador = 1;
    Avaliador = 2;
    Responsavel = 4; 
}
```

E, para persistir o valor no banco de dados, criar uma coluna do tipo inteiro. Assim, para definir que um usuário possui mais de um perfil, você pode utilizar o operador binário `|`:

```
john.perfil = Perfis.Administrador | Perfis.Avaliador;
```

Neste caso, o valor de `john.perfil` será 3, pois 1 | 2 = 3. E, se for necessário verificar se `john` possui um perfil em específico, basta utilizar o operador binário `&`:

```
if (john.perfil & Perfis.Administrador) {
    // John é um administrador
}
```

Esta lógica é segura em relação a garantir que o usuário possui determinado perfil pois como os valores na enumeração são potências de 2, a única combinação que resulta em 3 é 1 | 2.

Analisando em baixo nível, você basicamente possuirá um valor binário - neste exemplo, de tamanho 3: 000 - onde cada perfil é relacionado a um bit. Perfil Administrador seria o bit 0, Avaliador o bit 1 e Responsavel o bit 3. Se o usuário possui determinado perfil, basta setar como 1 o respectivo bit.

Eu comentei sobre essa técnica em Python nesta pergunta: [O que significa o operador "|=" em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/238219/5878)

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão é criar uma tabela `usuario`, uma tabela `perfil` e uma tabela `usuario_perfil`.

O usuário poderá ter mais de um perfil e um perfil pode pertencer a mais de um usuário, caracterizando um relacionamento `N-N`. Assim, você vai precisar de uma tabela intermediária, a `usuario_perfil`.

Exemplo de cadastro:

```
-- tabela usuario
id | nome
1  | Gustavo
2  | Augusto

-- tabela usuario_perfil
usuario_id | perfil_id
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 3
2          | 1

-- tabela perfil
id | nome
1  | Administrador
2  | Avaliador
3  | Responsável
```

É interessante criar uma *constraint* de chave única na tabela `usuario_perfil` nos campos `usuario_id` e `perfil_id`, para assegurar que um usuário não seja associado mais de uma vez ao mesmo perfil.