# operadorAritmetico

Tags: python, operadores

Bom dia,alguem sabe o que significa essa barra vertical em python?

> > > 4|3 = 
> > >       7
> > >
> > > 12|4 =
> > >       12

Comment: Jurandir, esta resposta irá te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238225/110782

Answer (score 1):

é um operador *or* binário, ele faz um *or* com os binários, compara *bit* a *bit* fazendo um *or* e dá o resultado.

4 em binário = 0100

3 em binário = 0011

0100 or 0011 = 0111

7 em binário = 0111

12 em binário = 1100