# Excluir uma variável que o programa recebe no input.split(" ") no Python

Tags: python

Estou trabalhando em um calculadora que precisa receber uma operação (como SUM, DIV, LOG10 etc.) e os operadores na mesma linha, ex:
SUM 2 4

Porém quando recebo LOG10 ou RAIZ o usuário só vai digitar um operador, exemplo:
RAIZ 36

O código funciona na parte de calcular e quando o usuário digita 3 strings no input, quando ele digita duas (como no caso da raiz) o programa gera erro.
A minha dificuldade é fazer com que no meu input exclua essa variável a mais, caso o usuário não a digite.

O código é:

```
operation, n1_str, n2_str = input().split(" ")
n1 = float(n1_str)
n2 = float(n2_str)

while((operation != "RAZ") | (operation != "LOG10")):

    if(operation == "SUM"):
        SUM = n1 + n2
        print("%.2f" %(SUM))
    elif(operation == "DIF"):
        DIF = n1 - n2
        print("%.2f" %(DIF))
    elif(operation == "DIV"):
        DIV = n1 / n2
        print(DIV)
    elif(operation == "MULT"):
        MULT = n1 * n2
        print("%.2f" %(MULT))
    elif(operation == "POT"):
        POT = n1 ** n2
        print("%.2f" %(POT))
    break

while((operation == "RAIZ") | (operation == "LOG10")):
    n1 = int(input())

    if (operation == "RAIZ"):
        RAIZ = n1 ** 0.5
        print("%.2f" %(RAIZ))
    else:
        LOG10 = math.log(n1, 10)
        print("%.2f" %(LOG10))
    break
```

Comment: É tão mais fácil pedir os dados de forma isolada. Não sei porque começou essa mania das pessoas que usam Python querer pegar um dado só e manipulá-lo. Há pouco tempo ninguém fazia assim e era mais feliz. Tanta cosia pode dar errada fazendo assim. Então ou faz de outra forma ou aceita o erro e entende que a pessoa deve se responsabilizar por digitar certo, que para um exercício tudo bem, mas para algo real tem que fazer todo tratamento, não apenas parcial.

Comment: Sim, seria muito mais fácil pegar de forma isolada. Mas o exercício pede a entrada dessa maneira. :/

Comment: interessante, eu nem sabia que python aceitava o operador "ou" como `|`, sempre usei `or`

Comment: Isabella, como não foi mencionada em nenhuma das respostas abaixo, acho importante mencionar que o seu uso do `while` é completa e absolutamente desnecessário. Repare que não importa qual o `input()`, ele sempre vai rodar uma só vez. Um loop que só roda uma vez não é um loop. Um simples `if` ali resolveria

Comment: @yoyo Na verdade o `|` é um [operador bitwise](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) e só "funciona" por coincidência, pelo fato do booleano em Python ser uma subclasse de `int`. Lembrando que os [operadores lógicos](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) como o `or` e `and` não são exatamente iguais, pois eles têm a característica de serem *short circuit* (só avalia a segunda condição caso necessário), e em Python eles retornam o valor da expressão avaliada (diferente do bitwise, que sempre retorna números)

Comment: @hkotsubo Achei interessantíssimo, vou aproveitar a deixa e linkar [esse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52949/para-que-servem-os-operadores), que achei interessante, apesar de não ser em python, e [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238219/o-que-significa-o-operador-em-python?rq=1). Muito instrutivos! Fica exposto a quem interessar

Answer (score -1):

Uma forma de solucionar o problema seria pegar o valor inteiro do input, dividi-lo em variáveis (utilizando o `split(" ")`) e armazenar as variáveis em uma lista:

```py
list_input = input().split(" ")
```

Feito isso, nós já podemos definir o valor das variáveis `operation` e `n1_str`, tendo em vista que estas sempre serão os valores armazenados no índice `0` e `1` da nossa lista:

```py
operation = list_input[0]
n1_str = list_input[1]
n1 = float(n1_str)
```

Agora, para verificarmos se haverá um terceiro valor basta medirmos o tamanho da lista. Caso ela tenha tamanho igual a 3, quer dizer que será necessário criarmos a variável `n2_str`:

```py
if(len(list_input) == 3):
   n2_str = list_input[2] 
   n2 = float(n2_str)
```

E daí já estará verificando corretamente :)

## Código completo

```py
import math

list_input = input().split(" ")
operation = list_input[0]
n1_str = list_input[1] 
n1 = float(n1_str)

if(len(list_input) == 3): 
   n2_str = list_input[2] 
   n2 = float(n2_str)

while((operation != "RAZ") | (operation != "LOG10")):

    if(operation == "SUM"):
        SUM = n1 + n2
        print("%.2f" %(SUM))
    elif(operation == "DIF"):
        DIF = n1 - n2
        print("%.2f" %(DIF))
    elif(operation == "DIV"):
        DIV = n1 / n2
        print(DIV)
    elif(operation == "MULT"):
        MULT = n1 * n2
        print("%.2f" %(MULT))
    elif(operation == "POT"):
        POT = n1 ** n2
        print("%.2f" %(POT))
    break

while((operation == "RAZ") | (operation == "LOG10")):

    if (operation == "RAZ"):
        RAIZ = n1 ** 0.5 
        print("%.2f" %(RAIZ))
    else:
        LOG10 = math.log(n1, 10) 
        print("%.2f" %(LOG10))
    break
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Answer (score -2):

então, essa foi o meu jeito que arrumar isso ai:

```
dados = input().split(" ")
if len(dados) == 3:
  operation, n1, n2 = dados
  n1 = flaot(n1)
  n2 = float(n2)
elif len(dados) == 2:
  operation, n1 = dados
        n1 = float(n1)
operation = operation.upper()
```

A função upper() no operation foi só pra evitar que dê erro caso a pessoa esqueça de escrever em maiúsculo, espero que tenha ajudado, forte abraço

Pelo código que você fez, acho que você sabe oque a função len() faz, mas caso não saiba, len() analisa o tamanho de uma lista ou string. Nesse caso, caso o tamanho da lista fosse de 3, significa que foi colocado a operação, o número 1 e o número 2. Mas caso o tamanho da lista fosse de 2, significa que foi colocado apenas a operação e o primeiro número.